# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'metadata_setup'

Tags: python

I have a directory structure like the following:

```
/
/setup
      /sqlalchemy
                 __init__.py
                 metadata_setup.py
/server
      /data
            __init__.py
            simulations.py
```

In simulations.py I have:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/setup/sqlalchemy')
import metadata_setup
```

but then I get the following error at the import statement:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'metadata_setup'
```

I tried adding a `__init__.py` to the root directory but I'm still getting the same results.  I'm running Python 3

Comment: try adding the full path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either insert full path or edit relative path like:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '../../../setup/sqlalchemy')
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.path[0]),'setup', 'sqlalchemy'))
import metadata_setup
```